# Remove string in between two characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I got a problem trying to remove words from a string file, e.g:

```
    String text = "data['danger.high'] && data['$safe.low'] || data['go.now']";
```

What I want to do its remove from the string everything that its between first single quote and '.' , the result I want its the following:

```
    result = "data[high] && data[low] || data[now]";
```

this would be the result I need.

So far what I got is

```
    String text = "data['danger.high'] && data['$safe.low'] || data['go.now']";
    text = text.replaceAll("\\'(.*?)\\.", "");
```

But this gives me

```
    result = "data[highlownow']"
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your answers, now my follow up question its lets say i have

```
    String text = "data['danger.high'] && (data['$safe.low'] || data['go.now'] == 'yes')";
```

I want the following result:

```
    result = "data[high] && (data[low] || data[now] == 'yes')";
```

Keeping the single quotes on this case the "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\'([$a-zA-Z]+)\\.", "'").replaceAll("'", "");
```

`text.replaceAll("\\'([$a-zA-Z]+)\\.", "'")` Will gove you:

```
 data['high'] && data['low'] || data['now']
```

and `.replaceAll("'", "");` will give you the desired result (without the `'`).

```
data[high] && data[low] || data[now]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be tweaked a little. Look for `$` characters and `[a-zA-Z]`. I assume you want to retain the single quotes. Let me know if that is not needed. You can use `replaceAll()` on the string again to remove the single quotes too.

```
        String text = "data['danger.high'] && data['$safe.low'] || data['go.now']";
        text = text.replaceAll("\\'([$a-zA-Z]+)\\.", "'");
        System.out.println(text);
```

Output

> data['high'] && data['low'] || data['now']

Comment: one more question, lets say my string was 
String text = "data['danger.high'] && (data['safe.low'] == 'some')";

how could i get the following result?

"data[high] && (data[low] == 'some'";

Comment: Please use the `help` button near the comment window to format those strings better. I cant understand your question.

Comment: oh i am sorry... i updated the question, you may see at the top

Answer (score 0):

your expression is removing the characters that start from second single quote 
thats why you are geiinng this result
You should prevent the replaceAll for character starting with ']

Use 
    text = text.replaceAll("\'([$a-zA-Z]+)\.", "'");